# Where can I view examples of the Android Studio themes and styles?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-theme, android-styles

I am currently learning App design with Android Studio. I'm playing around with the various styles and themes trying to see what's available. There are many things like Widget.AppCompat, Widget.Material3, Button.Small, Button.Borderless. The same applies to Themes like Theme.AppCompat, Theme.MaterialComponent, .DarkActionBar, .NoActionBar etc etc.

Is there any resources that show the general layout and appearance of these Themes and Styles or is it just a case of trawling through them to see what's what?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Android Material Design website here: https://m2.material.io/develop/android. It should give you everything you need.